# Using jQuery to load a page that require javascript in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple function to append floating resizable content to a page:

```
function CreateFloatingWindow(id) {
        var win = document.createElement('div');
        $(win).attr('id', id);
        $(win).height(100).width(300).css('background-color', 'red');
        $(win).resizable().draggable();
        $(win).appendTo($('body'));
        $(win).load('http://www.fantasy-mmorpg.com/fowiki/#1419~2');
}

CreateFloatingWindow('first');
```

The code works all right, except when the loaded page have some kind of javascript inside, in this case the result is a 'Please activate javascript' message
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1P31.jpg)

I think the message is handled by the target page itself, but I don't have access to its source.

Is there a way to make the target page understand that I have my javascript enabled even if it is loaded in a div via jQuery?

N.B. the above code requires jQuery and jQuery-UI to run properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been digging through and a couple of things to note:

Firstly this clause within the [jQuery .load() docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which might shed some light:

> **Script Execution**
>
> When calling `.load()` using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to `.html()` prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   `.load()` is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and ***thus are not executed***. An example of both cases can be seen below:
>
> Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will
>   successfully execute.
>
> 1 `$('#a').load('article.html');`
>
> However, in the following case, script
>   blocks in the document being loaded into #b are stripped out and not
>   executed:
>
> 1 `$('#b').load('article.html #target');`

Check against different browsers for the message 'Please Activate JavaScript', which I'm not sure if this is at Script level or Browser level. But I'm quite sure the "*Please Enabled JavaScript*" is probably the [HTML Fallback `<noscript>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/noscript) - If it's not executing any JavaScript at all.

Comment: This makes a point, but even removing the selector gives me the same message :/

Obviously I can 'see' the source of the page, but since it contains minified javascript I don't have access to the plain source code, to understand the logic and eventually use the parts I need.

As for the message, Firefox gives me the same message and I haven't tried it on IE since I don't know right now a method to run user scripts, I'll look into this further.

Comment: Apologies for making that assumption, but I suppose that same page then might have other minified scripts that have dependency checks for JavaScript/other scripts etc. I suppose from here without knowing the page to see, it's a bit difficult - as from my tests on including JavaScript files from `.load()`, they _do_ run successfully. I'll edit my answer to remove that accusation =)

Comment: didn't feel like an accusation at all =D  
Anyway, I fetched this page if you want to help me do some test: http://www.fantasy-mmorpg.com/fowiki/#1419~2  
I'm pretty sure the check is done in javascript, but I can't find a way to get around it... and I fear it could use some browser feature detection to display the message instead of a simple noscript tag

Comment: Aha.. almost immediately saw why, if you look at the DOM before page load - it says ("Please activate Javascript") inside `<div id="myContent">`, meaning the data is loaded from their own Ajax query and then appended to the myContent Div after the data is retrieved. Your code is working 100% fine as it's correctly getting the DOM that's there on page load, not when it's retrieved all it's data from their database.

Comment: Yup... you're right! Now I just have to understand if I want to go the easy way (use an iframe) or the hard way (try to mock theyr db request).
Thank you!